# loading a div 1 minute after the page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml

I have a div with id notifications in the home page. I don't want the div to be load when the page loads for the first time, I want it to load after 1 min. Is there any way in javascript or jquery to do what I want?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how you want to actually add your div into the DOM, but you can use setTimeout to delay for a minute. From [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout):

```
Calls a function or executes a code snippet after specified delay.
```

So something like this:

```
function appendDiv() {
  ... append code here...
}

timeoutID = window.setTimeout(appendDiv, 60000);
```

Comment: the function `appendDiv` has to be declared before the `setTimout`

Comment: @user2129151 If this answer took care of your problem, don't forget to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Sure :) in my example i use jQuery:

```
<div style="display:none" id="notifications"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    setTimeout(function() { 
        $.get('/notifications.php', function(result) {
            // build your notifications here
            // ...
            $('#notifications').show(); 
        }, 'json');
    }, 60000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: dont want to be a smartass, but note that the notification is loaded in your example. it just stays hidden.

Answer (score 0):

if the notification should not be in the DOM at all for the first minute, use following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout( function(){
    $("<div>")
      .html( "your notification message/markup" )
      .attr({ id : 'notification', ... })
      .appendTo( "body" /* or any other DOM element */ );
  }, 60*1000);
})
```

Comment: will I write the contents of <div> inside the square brackets `[]`. I am new to javascript so I am having problem understanding it.

Comment: no that was just a placeholder, sorry. see the updated answer

Comment: what is the second parameter of `.attr` used for,where you have written `...` and does the selector `$("<div>")` select all the divs because I only want to select the <div> with id notifications.

Comment: `$("<div>")` CREATES a div instead of selecting. comparable to `document.createElement("div")`. well `...` is for any html attributes you would like to add, i dont know. maybe a name maybe a title attribute.

Comment: Another problem that I am facing is that whenever I am adding a `<script></script>` inside .html function the outer script tag in which the `$(document).ready()` function resides is not working,it is saying that there is no starting tag found for `<script>`

Comment: i've never tried to insert a `<script>` with `$().html()`, so i cant help you there but it could be that jQuery sanitizes the contents to avoid hacking?

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery's `load` function:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#myDiv').load('divcontents.html');
}, 60 * 1000);
```

`divcontents.html` can be dynamically generated on the server.